# Android list view show hidden edit text when an item is clicked

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-emulator, android-edittext

I  want to hide the edit text and button field initially in list view and show that edit text and button only for a particular row (clicked row) in list view when that row is clicked.

I used following custom layout to create the list view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/emp_avatar"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:maxHeight="80dp"
android:maxWidth="80dp"
android:src="@drawable/person" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/emp_number"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/emp_avatar"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/emp_avatar"
android:text="Medium Text"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/empPin"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/emp_avatar"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/emp_number"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/emp_avatar"
android:ems="10"
android:inputType="number" 
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:visibility="invisible">

<requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

In this lay out I have used `android:visibility="invisible"`

Here is the code of Activity.java

```
public class MainPortal extends Activity {
private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
EditText et;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_portal);
populateEmployeeList();
//populsteListView();

ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.employeeListView);
ArrayAdapter<Employee> adapter = new MylistAdapter();
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.employeeListView);
list.setAdapter(adapter);

 list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {
              et.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

          }
        });


private void populateEmployeeList() {
  ...
}



private class MylistAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Employee>{


public MylistAdapter(){
    super(MainPortal.this,R.layout.item_view,employees);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View itemView = convertView;
    if(itemView==null){
        itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent,false);
    }
    Employee currentEmployee = employees.get(position);
    //Avatar
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.emp_avatar);
    imageView.setImageResource(currentEmployee.getAvatarId());
    //Employee number
    TextView emp_id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.emp_number);
    emp_id.setText(currentEmployee.getId());

    et = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.empPin);
    return itemView;
}
}
}
```

I used following codes withing the on click listener of list view to make edit text visible for item click.

```
editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);     
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But after clicking a row edit text field does not appears. What I'm doing wrong here ? does any body have an idea how to do this ?

Initialization of EditText:

```
View itemView = convertView;
        if(itemView==null){
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent,false);
        }

        et = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have set the visibility to gone. tat is why it does not appear. you set the visibility in xml. on click set the visibility to visible

Comment: I did change to editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  but problem remains

Comment: where have you initialized edittext?. you have done that in `getView`. edittext is not in your layout but in custom layout

Comment: try to use editText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); instead of editText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: I created the EditText instance at the bigining of the activity and initialized it withing public View getView(...) please look the updated question. Thanks

Comment: @Grant wrong `activity_main_portal` does not have edittext. But you the same in custom layout inflated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have EdiText in `item_view.xml` not in `activity_main_portal`. You are inflating a custom layout in `getView`

You need to initialize edittext

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {
          View v = (View)view.getParent();
          EditText ed1 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.empPin);  
          ed1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

      }
    });
```

Comment: one problem,,, when I click first row edit text field become visible but when I'm click second row edit text field doesn't appear what is the cause here ? Thanks!

Comment: log some info on listitem click  `position` will give you the index check the log and then debug

Comment: just use `EditText ed1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.empPin)` and remove `View v = (View)view.getParent()` and try

Comment: @Grant then you will have problem when you scroll your lsitview coz listview recycles views . it don't think what you are doing is good can you elaborate why you are doing this.

Comment: Yes exactly list view is repeated. I just want to show edit text field and button in list view when only the raw is clicked. What is the best way to do this I have no idea ?
Thanks!

Comment: @Grant i don't think its a good idea. i would suggest you rethink your design. you can infalte different layouts for your rows.